# How can I prevent having a tabindex on toolbar buttons in Quill

Tags: quill

I would like to prevent toolbar buttons in a Quill editor from having a tabindex. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Quill offers two ways to get a [toolbar](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/) at the two ends of the customization spectrum. One is you pass in an array of formats that you want and Quill builds the toolbar for you (in this case with a tabindex). The other is you give Quill whatever container you want (with or without a tabindex) and Quill attaches the appropriate handlers. If the former is not to your liking then the latter is the alternative.

Comment: could you please elaborate on your answer and include an example? I have read [this document](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/) that you have linked and I am not able to find anything about Tab Index on this page...